# Should I call close() in poll() loop

Tags: c, pipe, posix

The program below is prepared to catch stdout and stderr from a child process using the `fork()`/`exec()`/`poll()` combination. It works mostly fine but it fails at here:

```
if (close(pfds[j].fd) == -1)
    perror("close");
```

if the child process prints a lot of output. The error is: "close: Bad file descriptor". Moreover, this error does not occur each time. Say I run the program 10 times, perhaps it shows "close: Bad file descriptor" five times only. This keeps me thinking--should I keep this `close()` in the `poll()` loop at all?

(Note: The original program can be found [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/c/04_poc/06_subprocess/main-poll.c). For the sake of simplicity, all irrelevant error handling is removed.)

```
int exec(char* argv1) {
    int pipefd_out[2], pipefd_err[2];

    pipe(pipefd_out);
    pipe(pipefd_err);
    
    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid == 0) {
        close(pipefd_out[0]);
        close(pipefd_err[0]);
        dup2(pipefd_out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(pipefd_err[1], STDERR_FILENO);

        // Prepared a few possible cases, to demo different behaviors
        if (atoi(argv1) == 0) {
            execl("./sub.out", "./sub.out", NULL);
        } else if (atoi(argv1) == 1) {
            const char *const  args[] = {"./sub.out", "segfault", NULL};
            execv(args[0], args);
        } else if (atoi(argv1) == 2) {
            const char *const  args[] = {"./sub.out", "flooding", NULL};
            execv(args[0], args);
        } else if (atoi(argv1) == 3) {
            const char *const  args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", "/tmp/", NULL};
            execv(args[0], args);
        } else {            
            const char *const  args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l",
                "/path/that/definitely/does/not/exist/", NULL};
            execv(args[0], args);
        }
        perror("execl()/execv()");        
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    close(pipefd_out[1]);
    close(pipefd_err[1]);

    struct pollfd pfds[] = {
        { pipefd_out[0], POLLIN, 0 },
        { pipefd_err[0], POLLIN, 0 },
    };
    int nfds = sizeof(pfds) / sizeof(struct pollfd);    
    int num_open_fds = nfds;

    while (num_open_fds > 0) {
        int ready = poll(pfds, nfds, -1);
        if (ready == -1)
            perror("poll()");
        for (int j = 0; j < nfds; j++) {            
            if (pfds[j].revents != 0) {
                char buf[4096] = {0};
                if (pfds[j].revents & POLLIN) {
                    ssize_t s = read(pfds[j].fd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
                    if (s == -1)
                        perror("read()");
                    if (j == 0) { printf("<stdout>%s</stdout>\n", buf); }
                    else { printf("<stderr>%s</stderr>\n", buf); }
                    fflush(stdout);
                } else {                /* POLLERR | POLLHUP */
                    if (close(pfds[j].fd) == -1)
                        perror("close");
                    num_open_fds--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int status;
    waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("Child process exited normally, rc: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    } else {
        printf("Child process exited unexpectedly\n");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <0|1|2|3|4>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return exec(argv[1]);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The descriptor `pfds[j].fd` is one of your pipes. If you get an error or it's closed then you need to close it, *but* you also should not continue to pass it to `poll` in the next iteration.

And think about the case when it happens for `pfds[j].fd == pipefd_out[0]`. You need to rearrange the array to remove the closed pipe. Or create the array anew inside the loop just before `poll`.

---

Perhaps something like this:

```
if (close(pfds[j].fd) == -1)
    perror("close");
num_open_fds--;
if (pfds[j] == pipefd_out[0])
    pipefd_out[0] = -1;  // This descriptor is now closed
if (pfds[j] == pipefd_err[0])
    pipefd_err[0] = -1;  // This descriptor is now closed
```

And before `poll` you create the array:

```
size_t pfd_index = 0;
struct pollfd pfds[num_open_fds];
if (pipefd_out[0] != -1)
    pfds[pfd_index++] = (struct pollfd){ pipefd_out[0], POLLIN, 0 };
if (pipefd_err[0] != -1)
    pfds[pfd_index] = (struct pollfd){ pipefd_err[0], POLLIN, 0 };

int ready = poll(pfds, num_open_fds, -1);
// Etc...
```

Comment: my understanding of `poll()` is that `if (close(pfds[j].fd) == -1) perror("close");` is called once for each `fd` only. `num_open_fds--` is used in the outer `while()` loop, checking which `fd` should be `read()` is in the inner `for()` loop

Comment: @D.J.Elkind There's no guarantee that you would catch both pipes being closed in the same `poll` call. You need to continue to poll and read until all descriptors you poll are closed.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to translate what you said to a patch to my code--would it be possible for you to come up with some lines of code that fix the bug? It could be pseudocode as well.

Comment: My understanding of `poll()` is that what you do is unnecessary. If an `fd` is already `close()`, `if (pfds[j].revents != 0)` will always be false, so I will not end up `close()`ing it twice. The problem is, should I ever `close()` it once. On the 2nd part, this is the "irrelevant error hanlding" I mentioned in my question. They are omitted for the sake of simplicity.